# Running TestRig with wrong input string does not emit error message

Tags: antlr4

I made a grammar which constructs comparison between expressions as follows.

```
grammar EtlExpression;

/** The start rule; begin parsing here. */
prog   : comp ; 

comp   : expr ('='|'<='|'>='|'<'|'>') expr ;

expr   : expr ('*'|'/') expr   
       | expr ('+'|'-') expr   
       | '(' expr ')'         
       | func
       | ID                    
       | STR                    
       | NUM    
       ;

func   : ID '(' expr (',' expr)* ')' ;    // function 

STR    : '"' ('\\"'|.)*? '"' ;                       // match identifiers 
ID     : LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)* ;                    // match identifiers 
NUM    : '-'? ('.' DIGIT+ | DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT*)? ) ; // match number
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;                        // toss out whitespace

fragment
LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment
DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
```

then I ran testRig after compile.
The result is as follwoging.

```
java -cp .;C:\App\Antlr4\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig test.antlr.EtlExpression prog -tree
a < b = c
^Z
(prog (comp (expr a) < (expr b)))
```

The *comp* rule specifies only one comparison operand and I think this test input string should emit some kind error like "line 1:6 token recognition error at: '=' ", but it just ignores "= c" part.

Could you help me What's wrong with the grammar or how i can get the right message?
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The parser simply stops when it cannot match `=` and beyond it. If you force the parser to consume the entire input, an error will appear on your stdout. You can do that by adding `EOF` to your `prog` rule:

```
prog : comp EOF;
```